# When I use golang call the contract method,how can I confirm this trx status?

Tags: go, ethereum, web3js, go-ethereum, bsc

I mint the token to my account and it return transaction hash ,but I wnat to now this hash status .Like js can use callback function to wait this trx finished

```
     var promise = await token.mint("my account",1)
     console.log(promise.transactionHash)
```

golang

```
transaction, err := erc721.Mint(trx, common.HexToAddress("my account"), big.NewInt(int64(i)))
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(transaction.Hash().String())
```

Comment: You have to listen for all event logs and wait for confirmation on blockchain. Then you can call `client.TransactionReceipt()`.

Comment: I was trying to use this method at first, but I found that it does not support pending transactions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, you have to listen for event logs (preferably filtered for your address), and call for receipt after confirmation.

NOTE: Example is just to demonstrate necessary steps.

```golang
func waitForReceipt(c *ethclient.Client, hash, addr string) (*types.Receipt, error) {
    query := ethereum.FilterQuery{
        Addresses: []common.Address{addr},
    }
    var ch = make(chan types.Log)
    sub, err := c.SubscribeFilterLogs(ctx, query, ch) // subscribe to all logs for addr
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    for confirmed := false; !confirmed;  { // wait for confirmation on blockchain
        select {
        case err := <-sub.Err():
            return nil, err
        case vLog := <-ch:
            if vLog.TxHash.Hex() == hash {
                confirmed = true
            }
        }

    }
    return c.TransactionReceipt(ctx, hash) // call for receipt
}
```

Comment: Only this function?I think it's too cumbersome to write like this。BTW thanks Bro！！！

Comment: It depends, you can easily create callback function and have more control over whole flow.

Comment: Can I compare the nonce  of the current transaction with the nonce of the next transaction? As long as the nonce value is greater than the nonce of the previous trx, you can determine that the last transaction has been completed.

Comment: [Client.PendingNonceAt](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/getamis/go-ethereum/ethclient#Client.PendingNonceAt), comparing not complete and future transactions has to be done locally by storing value.